# Xamarin Binding Class

Tags: binding, delegates, scrollview, xamarin

I'm developing an app for iOS using Xamarin.

In my solution i've added a binding project to include some native library, but I've some trouble writing the ApiDefinition.cs

This is the original library:

```
@class AccordionView;
@protocol AccordionViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)accordion:(AccordionView *)accordion didChangeSelection:(NSIndexSet *)selection;
- (void)accordion:(AccordionView *)accordion heightUpdate:(NSInteger)height;
@end

@interface AccordionView : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
[..]
}

- (void)addHeader:(id)aHeader withView:(id)aView setBool:(BOOL)arrow;
- (void)setOriginalSize:(CGSize)size forIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView;
- (void)touchDown:(id)sender;
```

This is how i writed the ApiDefinitions.cs

```
[BaseType (typeof(UIView))]
interface AccordionView : UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    IntPtr Constructor(RectangleF frame);

    [Export ("addHeader:withView:setBool:")]
    void AddHeader(NSObject aHeader, NSObject aView, bool arrow);

    [Export ("touchDown:")]
    void TouchDown(NSObject sender);

    [Export ("setOriginalSize:forIndex:")]
    void SetOriginalSize(SizeF size, uint index);

    [Export ("scrollViewDidScroll:")]
    void ScrollViewDidScroll(UIScrollView scrollView);
}

[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
[Model]
interface AccordionViewDelegate
{
    [Export ("accordion:didChangeSelection:")]
    void DidChangeSelection(AccordionView accordion, NSIndexSet selection);

    [Export ("accordion:heightUpdate:")]
    void HeightUpdate(AccordionView accordion, int height);
}
```

My problem is on the UIScrollViewDelegate, I don't know how to "translate" it.
Someone can help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the walk-through using Objective Sharpie?

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/Walkthrough_Binding_objective-c_library/